# Print Current Line number in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a key-combination to print out the current line number?

This would be really useful in conjunction with the multiple selection method (cmd+D).

Comment: What do you mean by print? Print how? In the console?

Comment: Just print it out in sublime.

Comment: In the editor next to the cursor?

Comment: Correct. So would be really useful with multiple cursors.

Comment: I don't understand how it would useful, but no there's no keymap to do that. Still, I'll post a custom command you can use.

Comment: Well imagine you had a bug in a big file but you didn't know which line. You could var_dump in multiple places but what would you dump?? Well, a line number would be useful. But if you have 50 var_dumps you'd have to write the line number in 50 places.

Comment: This can be used in many ways, one of the ways I want to use this is, in my if-else structure where I want to print meaningful content if in case there is an error that occurs. use multi cursor select to create 25 or something cursors, and then echo a message saying something went wrong look on line number X.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there is a key binding or command do what you want, but I'm I'm unsure what it is that you mean by printing current line numbers in Sublime.

This is probably not at all what you want, but I'll leave it here for a while before I delete it. It might help you write a custom command for what you want.

## Command

```
import sublime_plugin

class InsertLineNumberCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit):
        for sel in self.view.sel():
            line_begin = self.view.rowcol(sel.begin())[0]
            line_end = self.view.rowcol(sel.end())[0]

            self.view.insert(edit, sel.end(), str(line_begin + 1))
```

## Key Binding:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+i"],
    "command": "insert_line_number"
}
```

## Usage

```
1: 
2: fizz|buzz
3:
```

Where `|` is the cursor, pressing `ctrl+i`:

```
1: 
2: fizz2|buzz
3:
```

With a multiple selection:

```
1: 
2: |fizz|2
3: buzz
4:
5: |fizz|5
6: buzz
7:
```

Comment: 1) Add `import sublime_plugin` at the top of the command. 2) Save command to file with any filename in `%AppData%\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User` 3) Ensure that no keybinding are in conflict. You can debug command calling by printing `sublime.log_commands(True)` in Sublime console.